# Compiling/Copying TypeScript declarations to out dir

Tags: javascript, typescript, node-modules

I have a module in TypeScript and when it is compiled, it is not copying my custom declaration files, such as the interfaces.

Configuration example:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["dist", "lib", "node_modules"]
}
```

When I compile the files, the declarations files and JavaScript files are created in the `lib` folder thanks to `declaration` flag. However, my custom interfaces are not copied to `lib` and they could be useful.

Structure example:

```
/lib
 - index.d.ts // It contains an error because it is trying to export interface, and it is not in the folder
 - index.js
 - example.js
 - example.d.ts
 - interface.d.ts // missing!!
/src
 - index.ts // Here is exported my interface and example function
 - example.ts
 - interface.d.ts
```

I could remove the `.d` extension, but then, the files would be generated as a JavaScript empty module.

It is possible to have that files in the `lib` folder directly when I compile with TypeScript, or I should copy the files after that with some command: ex `cp src/*.d.ts lib/`

I don't want to use the copy method because all interfaces would be exported, and I just want to export the interfaces exported/used in the module `index.d.ts`. Maybe there is not another option.

Comment: There is no option in TypeScript compiler to handle this. Best solution is to write your own script to copy these files to the output directory after compilation is done. See TypeScript team's response in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835.

Comment: @SnakeDrak are your interfaces from a 3rd party package? If your interfaces in `interfaces.d.ts` are **not** from a 3rd party package, then it is best practice to declare your interfaces within your normal `.ts` files. No need for an extra `.d.ts` file

Comment: @a1300 it is not a duplicated, my question is older than you shared...

Comment: @SnakeDrak ok deleted my comment

Comment: @SnakeDrak please answer the questions above (what purpose your declaration files have)

Comment: @a1300 It is a sample of a package that I want to share via NPM. I don't want to use normal `.ts` files because they are exported as empty module...

Comment: @SnakeDrak if I understand your problem correctly: You could simply put your interfaces within your **other** `.ts` files. You can declare a `class` in a `.ts` file and as many `interfaces` as you like. No need for an extra `interface.ts` or `interface.d.ts` file

Comment: @a1300 I think you didn't understand my question. I want to export some interfaces to be used by other modules. However, when the code is compiled, the interfaces exported are not moved to lib folder, so the other modules cannot use my interfaces. The only solution seems to be copy them with another script or manually.