# Copy original files during compilation?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to compile my `src` dir to a `dist` dir, but I'd also like to copy the original TypeScript files during compilation. Is there a way to specify this in the TypeScript config, or do I have to use a manual workaround to do it?

Comment: It seems you need to write a script to copy the files during compilation. please take a look at [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124944/compiling-copying-typescript-declarations-to-out-dir) and [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30835)

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Where do you want to copy the TS files? For what purpose? This question sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just keep using `src`. No-one requires you to use only `dist`.
2. No, `tsc` doesn't copy files, you'll need something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpy-cli
3. If you use build tools you may use copy plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-copy